# Usage of Azure Screen Resolution Utility with .yaml file

Tags: azure-devops, uwp, azure-pipelines, appium, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to run UI tests on Azure agent and one of the [guidelines provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest) states the use of [Screen Resolution Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-autotest.screen-resolution-utility-task&ssr=false#overview) to fix the screen resolution during UI tests in visible mode.

The problem with that is I am using .yaml files to configure pipeline but I could not find any document that states how to use this utility using .yaml files - even though it has been stated that it can be done.
[image]

Can someone please help me figure out how it is done or point me to the right document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can in clude this in your yaml file

```
- task: ScreenResolutionUtility@1
    inputs:
    displaySettings: 'specific'
    width: '1920'
    height: '1080'
```